# Send data to Fragments after it's been downloaded with Async Http

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-async-http

I'm parsing `JSON` with `Async Http` in Activity. Once when the data is successfully parsed, I want it to be available to both Fragments that the Activity is holding. One fragment is a `ListView` displaying the downloaded data and the other is a `Google MapView` displaying the data - not that it matters.

Once the data is downloaded:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
    // Data downloaded
}
```

I want to send it to both of those `fragments` and update the Map and `ListView` with data.

So I somehow want to implement some kind of listener in both of those fragments that will listen for `"onSuccess"` to occur and then use the data that it retrieved.

So if `onSuccess` occured before `Fragments` even instantiated, they will instantly display data. If not, they will wait for it.

Could someone help me implement this? I don't know how exactly to approach this.

Comment: `Observer` and `Observable` are maybe answer to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have these options :

- Use **EventBus** and send the data to both the fragments
- Store the data in the activity, use **LocalBroadcasrManager** and send
  broadcast which will let the fragments know that data has been
  downloaded and access data from fragments,i.e.
  `((MyActivity)getActivity()).getData();`

Comment: EventBus approach is a recommended one, use Google Guava.

Comment: I've used EventBus. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I used the EventBus too!

Comment: @MoD This is quite old question-answer, Now a days there are many other things, Eventbus is replaced by Rx and there are many ways to do things in better way like, Live data and ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler for that......you can put all your data in bundle and send that to handler and declare this handler in your fragment and pass this handler to your async class ,,,,when you get response just sendMessage to that handler.......

```
 Message msg =  new Message();
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

 bundle.putString("Test", "test value");
 msg.setData(bundle);

 handler.sendMessage(msg);

// Handler in the UI thread retrieves the data
// and can update the GUI as required

 private Handler handler = new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

Bundle bundle = msg.getData();

//set data to your views here.........

}

};
```

Hope it helps..

[Handler](http://shortcutsandroid.blogspot.in/2015/04/handler-in-android.html)

Comment: data that can be shown on map and in a list might not be suitable to be sent via Bundle, it can be a ping that data has arrived.

Comment: You can pass serializable list in case of list OR simply pass JSON and parse it there....

Answer (score 0):

Local Broadcasting of a message would be fit for this scenario.

Following points would also helpful for you.

1. instantiate fragments after getting data and pass it through setArgument(Bundle) method (if the response fetching is one time )
2. If data in onSucces() coming periodically then implement your own method to update UI of both fragment and call implemented method from Activity.onSuccess(...) method.

Answer (score 0):

Easy use with EventBus.

Dependency: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

```
implementation("org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.3.1")

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.greenrobot</groupId>
    <artifactId>eventbus-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Use it like: [Get Started](https://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/)

```
public class MessageEvent {

   public final String message;

   public MessageEvent(String message) {
      this.message = message;
   }
}
```

Subscribe to Data wherever you want:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), event.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Listen with:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```